# ThreeJS: how to set audio source to microphone

Tags: three.js

How do we set the audio source in ThreeJS to the microphone? And is there a way to not push the sound to the speakers? From the docs, I have this:

```
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );

 // create a global audio source
 var sound = new THREE.Audio( listener );
```

How next do I set the source to the microphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [site](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio/) you can try something like this:

```
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { audio: true, video: false } ).then( handleSuccess );

function handleSuccess( stream ) {

    var audio = new THREE.Audio( listener );

    var context = listener.context;
    var source = context.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
    audio.setNodeSource( source );

}
```

However, the code produces a weird audio output on my iMac with Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Mugen87. I did try as you suggested but it is creating an echo. I am using `this.sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( this.listener );` which I forgot to mention

Comment: An additional thought. I have got the code working (without positional audio) and without using ThreeJS viz. by using AudioContext directly. In that code, I **do not** direct the sound to the audioCtx destination. Is there such an equivalent in ThreeJS, where I do not connect the stream to the speakers (destination)?

Comment: No. The audio entities of `three.js` have a simple design and do not allow to create an arbitrary audio routing graph.

Comment: oh. ok. When you said it produces a wierd audio output did you too hear an echo?

Comment: It was more a squeaking noise. Same output in FF and Chrome.

Comment: That I have noticed happens if you are not using headphones. It, I believe, has something got to do with the noise from the output going back into the input. However, when I try the same with headphones I notice an echo. Thanks for your help. Will figure out and update this if I can "remedify" it. Meanwhile, you were dot on the way to connect the microphone. Thanks

Comment: @Mugen7: I was looking at the Audio.js code of ThreeJS and found that I could control not sending of the sound to the destination by disconnect the listener gain. The following line is where it is getting connected in the base library: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/audio/AudioListener.js#L19. I just set it in my code to: `listener.gain.disconnect()` and the echo vanished. Thanks